# Customize query in forms with specific arguments for ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I have an app called projects. One of the fields is `contributors` where list of users is stored with `ManyToManyField`. I'm trying to make it possible to add and remove users to and from the list. Adding has been fairly easy using `ModelChoiceField` with passed query set of all users. Removing a user from the list still eludes me. What I'm trying to understand is how and where to pass additional arguments so that I can process the query in form, so it would list only users from a specific project.

**Adding user**

**models.py**

```
# Model for projects
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    contributors = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    ...
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            "user",
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
# Add task to a project
@login_required()
def projects_adduser(request, id):

    # Fetch the project if it exists
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, id=id)

    # Form for adding users to contributors list
    form = AddUserForm(request.POST or None)

    # Validate the form
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.cleaned_data.get("user")
        project.contributors.add(user)
        project.save()
        messages.success(request, "User successfully added to project!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(project.get_edit_url())

    # Context dict to return for template
    context = {
        "title": "Add user to project: " + project.title,
        "form": form,
        "instance": project,
    }
    return render(request, template + '/form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass initial users queryset to form like this:

```
form = AddUserForm()
form.fields["user"].queryset = User.objects.filter(project=project)
```

Also, you don't need to call `project.save()`, `project.contributors.add(user)` already performing query to add m2m     connection

Comment: Cool! I didn't come up with this. I tested it myself. It is much much simpler and it seems better answer. Thanks I also learnt!

Comment: replying to your deleted question) it will return all users who have connection with project in `Project` model. SQL query will look something like this: `SELECT * FROM "auth_user" INNER JOIN "projects_project" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "projects_project"."user_id") WHERE "projects_project"."id" = 1`

Comment: Thank you, this is by far the simplest solution and exactly what I was looking for. It actually helped me remove some functions from views.py and simplify the code. I didn't know you could manipulate the form from outside of forms.py, and I was looking how to pass argument to the form itself inside the forms.py. heh... newbs, right? :P

Comment: glad to help ;)

Answer (score 3):

I decided to help people who use Django in stackoverflow from this weekend. I normally posted questions in here. I think It's time to give answer for people. It's my start! Exciting! I have used Django WebFramework for little less than 2 months. So my answer could be not enough or there is other better ways. But I came up this way to solve your problem. (Even I tested myself with my laptop with writing codes in person!)

My example code is here

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    contributors = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from barrierfree.models import Project
from barrierfree.forms import AddUserForm

# Create your views here.
def projects_adduser(request, id):

    # Fetch the project if it exists
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=id)
    pk_number_project = project.pk
    # Form for adding users to contributors list
    form = AddUserForm(request.POST, project=pk_number_project)

    # Validate the form
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.cleaned_data.get("user")
        print ("validated!")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Sucess')    
    # Context dict to return for template

    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form':form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/$', views.projects_adduser, {'id':1}, name='test'),
]
```

test.html

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from barrierfree.models import Project

class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            "user",
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk_num_project = kwargs.pop('project', None)
        print (pk_num_project)
        super(AddUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.all().filter(project__pk=pk_num_project)
```

here is explanation of how to do it.

When I read your code, it seems you pass specific project's pk number through view's parameter. Because you wrote `def projects_adduser(request, id):`. so I gave pk=1 in url for testing like this `url(r'^test/$', views.projects_adduser, {'id':1}, name='test')` and then you are going to pass project instance which matches with pk number when you initiate form instance. `form = AddUserForm(request.POST, project=pk_number_project)` then you are going to only show users who are in this project.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk_num_project = kwargs.pop('project', None)
        print (pk_num_project)
        super(AddUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.all().filter(project__pk=pk_num_project)
```

then you initialize what data you are going to show in form by overriding **init** method.

```
queryset = User.objects.all().filter(project__pk=pk_num_project)
```

you can filter like this because User and Project are N:N relationship.

I hope i understood your question properly and gave you proper answer:) Good luck on our journey with Django! Peace!

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I tested your answer worked as well, but I went devxplorer's as it was simpler. Though not needed in this specific example, this actually may come in handy in future apps like forums.

Comment: yes that's so true that devxplorer's answer is much simpler and better. I also learnt that there is simple way @devxplorer but what if you use generic form with class based view? i think It would be different case. I think you need to use get_form_kwargs and init method or more to do this. don't you?